# Rails Globalize - Eager Load Specific Translations by Locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, eager-loading, globalize

So I have a model in Rails, with `globalize` installed and configured:

`model.rb`

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  include TranslationWrites
  translates :column
  ...
end
```

I want to Eager Load "English" and "French" translations only, to prevent an N+1 query problem while looping. I've tried a few ways, but the query will not work as expected. Here's what I've tried:

```rb
Model.includes(:translations).first
```

Which executes the following SQL:

```
Model Load (...)
SELECT * FROM models ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1

Model::Translations Load (...)
SELECT * FROM model_translations WHERE model_translations.model_id = 1
```

That's perfect for Eager Loading all translations, but I only want "English" and "French". I tried this code:

```rb
Model.includes(:translations).where(translations: { locale: ['en', 'fr'] }).first
```

That runs the following incorrect SQL:

```
Model Load (...)
SELECT * FROM models LEFT OUTER JOIN model_translations ON model_translations.model_id = models.id WHERE translations.locale IN ('en', 'fr')

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'translations.locale' ...)
```

As you can see, conditional eager loading (as see [on this tutorial](https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/conditional-eager-loading-in-rails-9b1c1c592897)) doesn't seem to work...

Lastly, [Globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize#scoping-objects-by-those-with-translations) has the `with_translations(['en', 'fr'])` method, but that scopes the `Model`s returned to only those that **have** the specified translations. I need those Models **regardless of whether or not they have "English" or "French"**. If you're familiar with Laravel, it's the difference between `with()` and `whereHas()`:

```php
// Returns all `Model` instances, and each `$model->translations` will have `en` and `fr` only.
Model::with(['translations' => function($query) {
  $query->whereIn('locale', ['en', 'fr'])
})->get();

// Only returns `Model` instances that have `en` or `fr` translations, but `$model->translations` will include all translations
$models = Model::whereHas('translations', function($query) {
  $query->whereIn('locale', ['en', 'fr'])
})->get();
```

Has anyone come across this? I need an efficient way to only load English and French translations for each Model in the database, regardless of whether or not that translations actually exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, in your `.where` method you should use the real table name, not the relationship's name between your models, so try with:

```
Model.includes(:translations).where(model_translations: { locale: ['en', 'fr'] }).first
```

Comment: Beautiful! I guess I misunderstood how that chained `.where()` method worked; the tutorial uses the model and table `books`, so I assumed it was using the relationship name. Thanks for the clarification!